# Lowest chart low when stochastic is low

Tags: pine-script

I want to draw the lowest low on the chart when the Stochastic K is below 55.

My code so far is:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Lows", shorttitle="Low of low", overlay=true)

periodK = input(14, title="K", minval=1)

smoothK = input(3, title="Smooth", minval=1)
k = sma(stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)

lowestInCycle(series) =>
    min=101.0
    if series < 55
        if series < min
            min := series
    else
        min:=na
    min != 101.0

plotshape(lowestInCycle(k), title="Test", location=location.belowbar, color=color.red, transp=0, style=shape.triangleup, text="L")
```

I also have modified the Stochastic indicator to show crosses when it is below 55 and gets lower and lower on K. This is just for reference in the image.

**I want to mark only the lowest low of price in every 'stochastic below 55 cluster'.**

How can this be done? Any help is appreciated.

PS. Needless to say I am a beginner. Just by playing since I wrote the post I can make the code better.

Thanks in advance

[image: What I get is something like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses a label to id the lowest k in the under 55 cycle, so you will be limited to seeing a label for only the last 500 cycles. When the indicator is running in realtime, the bar with the lowest k value can change until the under 55 cycle is completed. The value of the lowest k value is printed with the label:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Lows", shorttitle="Low of low", overlay=true, max_labels_count = 500)

periodK = input(14, title="K", minval=1)

smoothK = input(3, title="Smooth", minval=1)
k = sma(stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)

lowestInCycle(series) =>
    _xDn = crossunder(series, 55)
    _xUp = crossover(series, 55)
    var label _label = na
    var float _min = na
    if _xDn
        // We enter a cycle; create a new label (each cycle has its own label).
        _min := series
        _label := label.new(bar_index, close, tostring(_min, "#.##"), yloc = yloc.belowbar, color = color.red, textcolor = color.red, style = label.style_arrowup)
        // This is just so that all `if` blocks return a float, otherwise compiler complains.
        float(na)
    else if _xUp
        // We exit a cycle.
        _min := na
    else if not na(_min)
        // We are in a cycle; get new minimal value if there is one.
        _min := min(_min, series)
    if change(_min) < 0
        // We are in a cycle and a new minimum was found; update the cycle's label.
        label.set_x(_label, bar_index)
        label.set_text(_label, tostring(_min, "#.##"))

lowestInCycle(k)
// We need to  plot something, otherwise compiler complains.
plot(na)
```

This shows the code in action, with a Stoch underneath showing cylcles with a red background:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wanted the low on the price's low not the K's low, but it was just a matter of changing `_min : low` and then doing the `_min := min(_min, low)`